# how to display Y axis labels inside chart area

Tags: c#, .net, mschart

I have a time axis and I want to display my Y axis labels inside the chart area instead of outside

here is my code

```
        Series newSeries = new Series("hkld");
        newSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        newSeries.BorderWidth = 2;
        newSeries.Color = Color.OrangeRed;
        newSeries.XValueType = ChartVal

        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsReversed = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 2;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Gray;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 1000000; 
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 200000; //major interval
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Interval = 20000; //minor interval
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dot;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 2;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "HH:mm:ss";
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 2;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Gray;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MinorGrid.IntervalType =               DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MinorGrid.Interval = 2;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MinorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].BorderColor = Color.Black;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].BorderWidth = 3;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.X = 5;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Y = 5;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Width = 90;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Height = 90;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.Height = 100;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.Width = 80;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.X = 20;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Auto = false;
```

**Here is a pic of my chart :**

[image]

**And here is what i want to achieve :**

[image]

**NOTE : my chart is a real time chart, so the time value will be updated and goes up as the time continues (dynamic axis)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can move the labels but you can move the axis along with the labels. To do so set a suitable value for the [`AxisX.Crossing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.crossing?view=netframework-4.7.2).

MSDN:

> Setting this property for a primary axis will determine where the
>   other primary axis crosses it, and similarly setting it for a
>   secondary axis will determine where the other secondary axis crosses
>   it. For example, setting the Crossing property of the primary X-axis
>   determines where the primary Y-axis will cross it.
>
> Four modes can be used for the Crossing property of an axis:
>
> - "Auto", which means that the crossing value will be set to the minimum or maximum value for the relevant axis...
> - "Minimum", which means the crossing value of the axis will be its minimum value...
> - "Maximum", which means the crossing value of the axis will be its maximum value...
> - A specified double value that is between the minimum and maximum values for the  relevant axis...

This moves it to the x-value of the last datapoint:

```
Axixs ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
ax.Crossing = mySeries.Points.Last().XValue;
```

You can use fixed values if you know your data..

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's what i need 